# Java Duplicate Prefix

Tags: java, spring, gradle, build, jhipster

im having troubles building my jhipster application with the following code. When i build it with gradle, it throws out this error:

> Task :compileJava
> Note: Hibernate JPA 2 Static-Metamodel Generator 5.3.13.Final
> C:\Users\softdew\Documents\store\src\main\java\com\mycompany\store\config\CloudDatabaseConfiguration.java:25: error: Duplicate `@ConfigurationProperties` definition for prefix 'spring.datasource.hikari'
> public DataSource dataSource(CacheManager cacheManager) {
> ^

Im new in java development and im not so familiar with spring boot and all that. So right now im very confused, i looked at different stackoverflow entries and i found some explanations but i couldnt solve and use them for my code, i will be very happy if anyone explains this in detail and helps me to understand how the code below works.

Thanks everyone <3

```
   package com.myapp.config;
import org.hibernate.*;
import org.hibernate.cfg.*;



import io.github.jhipster.config.JHipsterProperties;
import io.github.jhipster.config.JHipsterConstants;



import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigureBefore;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.JCacheManagerCustomizer;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernatePropertiesCustomizer;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.EnableCaching;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import javax.cache.CacheManager;


import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.cloud.config.java.AbstractCloudConfig;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.*;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;






@Profile(JHipsterConstants.SPRING_PROFILE_CLOUD)

public class CloudDatabaseConfiguration extends AbstractCloudConfig {

    public final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CloudDatabaseConfiguration.class);
    
    public static final String CLOUD_CONFIGURATION_HIKARI_PREFIX = "spring.datasource.hikari";

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(CLOUD_CONFIGURATION_HIKARI_PREFIX)
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        log.info("Configuring JDBC datasource from a cloud provider");
        return connectionFactory().dataSource();
    }
}
```

Comment: Did this happen at the end of project generation or after you modified the generated project?

Comment: I imported my jdl file into project via command line. After that i tried to build with gradle wrapper and this error came out.

Comment: OK, so it's probably a bug, you should close this question and open an issue on github with output of `jhipster info` so that we can try to reproduce

Answer (score 0):

I got in the same trouble,
You are for sur using in your imported file a different ***packageName***.
When generating you get two classes. so in order to get rid of this error, use the same packageName as before

Comment: I am having the same problem. @Lho Ben Please can you help me how did you resolve this ? Thanks.